# Java 8 Optional inside Optional

Tags: java, java-8

I am using Optional for transaction Management in the following way

```
    EmployeeBo transactionResult =
    Optional.ofNullable(service.save(employeeBo))
        .filter(o -> o.getId() !=null && o.getId() > 0)
        .map(employeeBo1 -> {
          Boolean resultFileController =
              Optional.ofNullable(fileController.increaseUsedById(Authorization, fileIds))
                  .filter(o1 -> o1.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK))
                  .map(fileResponse -> {
                    ResponseEntity<ObjectResponseBo> userResponse = null;
                    try {
                      userResponse = userService.addUser(Authorization, populateUser(employeeBo.getId()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Boolean resultUserService = Optional.ofNullable(userResponse)
                        .filter(o2 -> o2.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.CREATED))
                        .map(o3 -> {
                          logger.debug(()-> "User Added successfully !! ");
                          return true;
                        }).orElseGet(() -> {
                          logger.debug(()->"User Not Added successfully !! ");
                          return false;
                        });
                    //Rollback File
                    if (resultUserService == Boolean.FALSE) {
                      fileController.decreaseUsedById(Authorization, fileIds);
                      logger.debug(()->"File Rollbacked !! ");
                      return false;
                    }
                    logger.debug(()->"File Update successfully !! ");
                    return true;
                  }).orElseGet(() -> {
                    logger.debug(()->"File record updation failed !! ");
                    return false;
                  });
          //Rollback Employee
          if (resultFileController == Boolean.FALSE) {
            service.delete(employeeBo1.getId());
            logger.debug(()->"Rollback Company successfully !! ");
            return employeeBo;
          }
          logger.debug(()->"Company Saved successfully !! ");
          return employeeBo1;
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
        logger.debug(()->"Company Saved failed !! ");
        return null;
        });
```

its working fine. but code is not easily readable as optional inside option etc. whats another way to achieve this rollback chaining ? as if any transaction fail  , it intimate previous transaction I have failed and so on ..

any other good solution ?

Comment: this is the completly wrong use of `Optional` as it should only be used by methods as a return value. You better use normal nullchecks, as your code is not really readable at this very moment

Comment: This looks at first glance as if it was terribly complicated by the use of optional. Why not just good old `if` statements? `Optional.ofNullable(...).filter(...).map(...).orElseGet(...)` is a terrible way to write logic like that.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [blog](https://medium.com/@bgourlie/java-s-optional-the-do-s-and-don-ts-4323151bc073)

Comment: the way you have it right now, I doubt it someone will actually take the time to figure this one out and re-factor...

Comment: Java doesn't really have the language support for this; Trying to write code based on optionals like that doesn't really work with the API they provide you. You're better off only using them for very simple things.

Comment: Instead of `boolean b = o.map(x -> true).orElseGet(() -> false);`, you should simply use `boolean b = o.isPresent();`, but, of course, then you can’t clutter it with debug statements. Further, instead of `if(condition == Boolean.FALSE) …`, you should write `if(!condition)`.